# Python JSON input order

Tags: python, json, ordereddictionary

I am attempting to read a JSON file containing data which I want to keep in order as it is a mathematical equation which can't change. I have tried using OrderedDict() however this doesn't work (or I can't get it to work).

Here is the code I am using:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

json_data = open('example3.json')
data = OrderedDict(json.load(json_data))

print (json.dumps(data))
```

Could anyone shine some light as to why this is not working?

Kind regards
Craig

Comment: Just note that the json spec explicitely mentions that json objects (which translate to `dict`s in Python) are "an _unordered_ collection of key:value pairs" - IOW, you should __not__ rely on keys order in json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json.load` will load the json data into a dictionary. You then convert this dictionary to an `OrderedDict`. Unfortunately, because it was a dictionary *first* the order could have already changed before it is "set" in the `OrderedDict`.

To load the json directly into an `OrderedDict` you can use the keyword argument `object_pairs_hook` with `OrderedDict`. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) for more details.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

json_data = open('example3.json')
data = json.load(json_data, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```